# texlive-2020 / xetex can't find shared library libfontconfig.so.1

Tags: installing, texlive-2020

I installed vanilla TeX Live 2020 on my Debian-based system, [Knoppix 8.6.1](https://www.knopper.net/knoppix/knoppix861-en.html), according to the manual at http://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html

Whenever I try to start xelatex I get this error-message:

```
$ xelatex
xelatex: error while loading shared libraries: libfontconfig.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Whenever I try to start xetex I get this error-message:

```
$ xetex
xetex: error while loading shared libraries: libfontconfig.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

**Question:**

What am I to do to get xetex / xelatex to work ?

---

`$ sudo apt-get install libfontconfig1`

yields the following message:

`libfontconfig1 is already the latest version (2.13.1-2).`

---

`$ sudo apt-get install fontconfig`

yields the following message:

`fontconfig  is already the latest version (2.13.1-2).`

---

**Edit/Answer:**

Shame on me:

I found out that the TeX Live installer assumed the wrong platform:

x86_64-linux  instead of  i386-linux .

The system in question, [Knoppix 8.6.1](https://www.knopper.net/knoppix/knoppix861-en.html), is based on Debian/stable (buster), with some packages from Debian/testing and unstable (sid) for newer graphics drivers or desktop software packages. It uses Linux kernel 5.3.5 and Xorg 7.7 (core 1.20.4).

The system in question can be used as a Live-System which can be installed on DVD/USB-stick/(micro) SD-memory-card as well.

Therefore i386-binaries are used by this system no matter if the machine in use is i386 or x86_64.

I ran this system on an x86_64-machine.

Thus the command `arch` yielded: `x86_64`
while the command `dpkg --print-architecture` yielded `i386`.

The TeX Live Installer "assumed" an x86_64-platform **which I didn't realize**.

If you run the installer as described in the linked manual, i.e., via the command `sudo ./install-tl -gui`, then on `x86_64`-machines installation for `x86_64`-platforms is pre-entered in the "Advanced" settings of the GUI **no matter if Debian-i386-binaries are in use** (which is possible with `x86_64`-machines). And you can't change this pre-entered setting in the GUI-"Advanced"-screen but only have i386-binaries installed additionally to the x86_64-binaries.

Removing the erroneous x86_64-TeX Live installation and running the installer with the `-force-platform`-option, i.e., via the command `sudo ./install-tl -gui -force-platform i386-linux` now gave me a TeX Live-installation with i386-binaries where everything works smoothly.

Sorry for the noise.

Comment: Run `LD_DEBUG=libs xetex` to see where XeTeX is looking for libraries.

Comment: Try also rebuilding the `ld.so.cache` using `sudo sh -c "rm /etc/ld.so.cache; ldconfig"`

Comment: Because on Debian the file is located at `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1` but that is not looked up by your dynamic linker.

Comment: A last thing to try would be to list all files included in `libfontconfig1` using `dpkg -L libfontconfig1` to see where `libfontconfig.so.1` is installed.

Comment: Could you please share what Debian-based distro you are using? (`cat /etc/os-release`)  That would allow others to try to reproduce your issue in a VM or a container.

Comment: @HenriMenke I edited my question to add that information. Meanwhile I found the reason for the problem: Binaries for the wrong platform were automatically installed by the TeX Live installer: x86_64 instead of i386 because the machine is x86_64 while the Debian-binaries in use (a Live System on USB-stick which I am going to remaster) are i386.

Comment: Good to hear that you managed to resolve the issue.

Comment: @HenriMenke I owe you an apology: You were the only one who took care of my problem. Instead of being grateful for that, I got -eh- bitchy because I was unjustifiably frustrated about your wondering if it was really Debian. The shameful thing is that I have thus demonstrated a double standard: I didn't like what I often do myself when I take on the role of the helper: Being skeptical of questioners' descriptions and assumptions at times and making sure of the real circumstances. So now my apologies: Please forgive me. And thanks for the help.

Comment: you could raise this on texlive list see if the platform detection can catch this case

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Done.

Comment: @UlrichDiez No worries :)

Answer (score 1):

While the TeX Live installer could detect this specific case (as mentioned on the mailing list, and I will discuss this with Karl), a solution could be to

```
dpkg --add-architecture amd64
apt-get update
apt-get install libfontconfig1:amd64
```

should work, too.

Comment: You are right - as long as you focus only on the x86_64-machine which
was in use by me the day when my installing-attempts took place.
The scenario described by me focuses on a Live System runable from
USB-Stick/(micro) SD-card/DVD (after remastering) which is intended
to work both on i386-platforms and on x86_64-platforms.
Installing TeX Live x86_64-linux binaries and making xetex work by
additionally installing libfontconfig1:amd64 would lead to TeX Live
not working  when running the Live System in question on i386-machines.

Comment: That is true, but for these very specific cases the `--force-platform` is here. I don't think we can and want to try to detect all combinations (next is arm64 running on amd64? Or qemu runs, ...).

Comment: That's why in the mailing list I wrote that probably it is sufficient to mention in the short installation-tutorials that there are edge scenarios where you are on your own with making sure that binaries for the correct platform are installed by applying the -force-platform-option.  I also think that people who play around with such specific scenarios as mine should know on their own what they need to pay attention to. Shame in me that I did not see it myself_before_asking my question. Nonetheless I will not delete the question in case s.b. else stumbles over similar problems.

Comment: Instead of detecting this case the GUI could let people change the pre-entered setting in the GUI-"Advanced"-screen? On the other hand being urged to use the "--force-platform"-switch might be a good thing as this way one is urged to read the installation manual so that one knows what one is doing. ;-)